# Elementor Templates filter

Tags: wordpress, templates, elementor, wordpress-shortcode

Can anybody help me with a feature in which I can filter Elementor templates based on categories or template names and I want a filter bar for this. I have created some templates and I want to show them in a page using filter bar. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

From wp admin > templates

you can manage all your elementor templates and also you get a finder search bar using which you can search by name.

And there's no other way to filter elementor templates.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  but I want this feature in an Elementor page. I have created some templates and I want to show them in a page using filter bar.